# how to migrate GoDaddy MS-SQL backup to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, postgresql

I have an Asp.Net web application hosted on GoDaddy's windows server. I'm creating the same app on Ruby on Rails now, is there a way to import MSSQL DB backup file to my rails app? I'm using PostgreSQL for Rails app.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have MSSQL database backup file. There are three different ways you can use to import/restore a database backup to your rails application.

**First:**
    `psql -U <username> <database_name> < my_backup.psql`

**Second:** `pg_restore -U <username> -h localhost -O -d <database_name> my_backup.dump`

**Third (Restore SQL Backup/Dump):**

1. Log in as the superuser: `sudo su - postgres` or `sudo -u postgres psql`
2. Then run the command: `psql averlent_development < my_backup.sql`

P.S: The third option will work if you have superuser password.